# Error when launching: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer

Tags: multiple-monitors, live-usb

I am having a problem with my live Ubuntu instance. I launch it (it goes through Ventoy, but that does not matter as I have tried installing tails directly on the USB and I have had the same error) and enter grub, then I choose live Ubuntu and I get the error in the picture. If I wait a little bit I hear the sound of Ubuntu starting up, but there is no picture and I start getting weirdly colored pixels as shown in the image. Interestingly, this does not happen if I try to launch it on my TV, (have it connected as a monitor via HDMI). I still get the error, but it launches just fine.

[image]

My monitor is 1680x1050, if this is important. (it is set as a secondary in Windows, but I use it as a primary)
Graphics card is Nvidia GTX 970.
It is connected via a DVI cable to my monitor.
It is connected via a HDMI cable to my TV.

I have tried:

-Launching it in safe mode. It works that way but the resolution is low. I want a proper image.

- Adding noapic after splash quiet in grub.
- Disabling the the module with the command `tpm_crb.blacklist=yes`

As I have said before, some time ago, I was installing Tails and faced the same issue.

One of the solutions I found on the internet said to disable tpm, but I think it is not smart to do so.